# Limit of Overlays for Google Maps SDK for iOS encountered

Tags: ios, maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

The SDK seems like it cannot handle the 2700+ lines of paths we are trying to overlay on the map. When trying to load with 750, it crashed.

Any feedback/experience on these items would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please split this into 2 individual questions?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specific nature of your crash, it's hard to say.  But if by "lines of paths" you are referring to the GMSPolyLine construct, then this may qualify as feedback/experience: [GMSPolyLine Very Large Memory Spike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15442262/gmspolyline-very-large-memory-spike).

So far we have not found a work around, but when we do, we will update the linked issue.

(PS: I'd have posted this as a comment but I do not yet have sufficient rep points to do so.)